# can someone please can point out what is going wrong with this jquery or css that has been adapted from a snippet found

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've taken this jquery snippet from a post made years ago, but i've been unable to adapt it for what I want, simply highlighting in some way the text in the navigation on the left hand side based on which div is within view, It's most likely something really stupid going wrong, but I would just like a little help in getting the answer. Apologies for the dispicable formatting, I'm new!

**html:**

```
    <div class="navwrap">
    <nav>
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#two" class="links">PotD </a></li>
        <li><a href="#three" class="links">Description </a></li>
        <li><a href="#four" class="links">Extra </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <div class="container" id="two">

        <div class="container-2-content" id="PotD">
          <h2> Aquilegia vulgaris </h2>
          <h3> "common columbine" </h3>
        </div>
  </div>

<div class="container" id="three">

    <div class="container-3-content"  id="Description">
      <h2> Description </h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="four" >

    <div class="container-4-content"  id="Extra">
      <h2> Extra </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
li a:hover, li.a.active{

  cursor:pointer;
  font-size:30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: rgb(255, 253, 234);
  border-top: 3px solid rgb(255, 253, 234);
  border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(255, 253, 234);

}
```

**jquery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var $sections = $('.container');


  $(window).scroll(function(){


    var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();


    var $currentSection


    $sections.each(function(){

      var divPosition = $(this).offset().top;


      if( divPosition - 1 < currentScroll ){

        $currentSection = $(this);


      }


      var id = $currentSection.attr('id');
     $('').removeClass('active');
     $("[href=#"+id+"]").addClass('active');

    })

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are looking for something called [ScrollSpy](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/scrollspy/). The bootstrap framework has it ready to go.